# Jquery menu created and no works

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

I created my own script for show menu in head of my website but I have some problems

The basic problem is that

1. When i put my mouse over the link for display the menu , the menu shows perfectly in the first moment ,
2. But if i put the mouse over the div - show until - of menu show , this menu hide all time and doesn't stay

With this script I am trying to show `div` and when the mouse go out of this `div` ,hide it

My Script is this :

```
function menu(id,width,color)
{

$(".men"+id).mouseover(function(e) {

//
//$(".m"+id).show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 500);
//$(".m"+id).show(500);

$(".m"+id).css("width",""+width);
$(".m"+id).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
$(".m"+id).css("background-color",""+color);

e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImediatePropagation();

});

$(".m"+id).mouseout(function(e) {


$(this).hide(500);
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImediatePropagation();

});

}
```

CSS Style :

```
#content_menu
{
margin-top:7px;
position:absolute;
min-height:50px;
height:auto;
border:1px solid;
text-align:left;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
z-index:2;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity:0.8;
-khtml-opacity: 0.8;
opacity: 0.8;
}

#content_menu_into
{
position:relative;
width:98%;
min-height:28px;
height:auto;
line-height:28px;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px;
color:#000000;
padding-left:2%;
text-align:left;
}
```

And for call script :

```
   <a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:menu('1','200','#000000');" class="men1">
   Home Web Menu
   </a>


    <div id="content_menu" class="m1" style="display:none;">
    <div id="content_menu_into">
    Home
    News
    Articles
    Users
    Vote
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thank´s for the help , Happy New Year !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to fix:

1. (Which doesn't answer your question): You are running `menu` function on `mouseover` event. And what you do on `menu` is binding the `mouseover` (and the `mouseout`). That is a bit redundant. You should call `menu` at `document.ready`.
2. (Which does answer your question): You should hide the menu only when the mouse is out of both: `m1` and `men1`.

Just by curiosity: Why aren't you using any of all the existing menu plugins?

Comment: tell me which plugin works as my script 5 lines an no more , i only wat that , but if you think or know some code ok perfect and please you can put the code for see the problem , thank´s , happy new year , regards !!!

Comment: You can google and will find plenty of plugins. You can pick the one you like the most. http://bit.ly/Vf1y5b